# TelegramBot время работы

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Разрабатываю чат-бота и столкнулась с такими проблемами, поделитесь опытом, может у кого-то было.
1. Как установить ограничительное время на работу чат-бота, допустим нужно, чтобы он работал с 8.00 до 20.00?
2. Чат-бот для онлайн-заказа. Как подтвердить намерения пользователя? Знаю, есть возможность подтверждения по смс коду или что-то такое, но это платно. Может можно как-то использовать номер телефона клиента?

Answer (score 1):

1. если допустить что бот крутится на linux и запускается service, можно повесить задание в cron на запуск службы в 8 и остановку в 20
   либо воспользоваться [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html)

2. можно запрашивать у пользователя номер телефона и если он отправит (тот что привязан к Telegram) работать с клиентом дальше

   ```
   def request_phone(message):
       user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
       button_phone = types.KeyboardButton(text="", request_contact=True)
       user_markup.add(button_phone)
       send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Поделитесь своим номером, чтобы я нашёл Ваши заказы',
                    reply_markup=user_markup)
   ```